# Three levels path in react js router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <div>
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path='/react' component={Dashboard} />
         <Route exact path='/react/createEmployeeForm' component={CreateEmployee} />
         <Route exact path='/react/createTargetedForm' component={CreateTargeted} />
         <Route exact path='/react/structureIndex' component={FormStructuresIndex} />
         <Route exact path='/react/structure/:id' component={FormStructureShow} />
         <Route exact path='/react/form/type' component={FormType} />
       </Switch>
   </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The route with three levels paths like: `'/react/structure/:id'`...and `'/react/form/type'` are not working...returning 404 Not Found page

Using laravel with all its routes pointing to react front end..

```
Route::view('/{path?}', 'reactFrontEnd');

Auth::routes();
```

Comment: pass `exact` props to `Route`

Comment: Even when all the routes are ```exact```...the page return 404

Comment: Everything looks ok to me here. you facing this issue on local server?

Comment: This is not how you nest your routes. When you do like that react-router dosent find a path `/react/form/type` and so on. React-router works in segmants => each `/` means a new segmant. So url `localhost/react/form/type` would mean 3 segmants `react` `form` and `type` but since you register them as a one segmant it can not find it as its searchign for a segmant `react/form/type`. React-router has a simple tutorial on how you nest routes https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting . Basically, you need a route inside the routed component so in the component `Dashboard` doa  route for `/form`

Comment: @Lith he is not nesting the routes, these are plain top level routes. and it can be anything, in this case all path props are vaild and correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was with Laravel routing...Laravel was returning 404. not React js

```
Route::view('{path}', 'reactFrontEnd')->where('path', '([A-z\d\-\/_.]+)?');
```